# How to update a particular column of each row of a table?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hi I would like to update my last column with values from a text file which I will receive in later stages.

Currently i am able to update all rows of the last column at a time using jquery. But i want to read from a file (output.txt) and update each row of the table for that column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ms-listviewtable').find('td').eq(3).text('changedValue');
});

<table class=ms-listviewtable>
    <tr class="ms-itmhover">
        <td class="ms-vb2">Value1</td>
        <td class="ms-vb2">Value2</td>
        <td class="ms-vb2">Value3</td>
        <td class="ms-vb2 ms-lastCell">Value4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you looking for help with the file input? Your question isn't 100% clear.

Comment: Where is the file located? If it's on the server you can read it using AJAX. If it's on the client, I don't think you can access it with Javascript.

Comment: It is on the linux server. I am not sure how to pick up this file(output.txt in /var/www/html) and read each line and update the column value of each row individually. I will have 10 rows always and the generated output.txt will also have 10 rows always. I would like to read each line and update the last column of each row with this values. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, then try this jQuery:

```
var file = 'http://foo.com/foo.txt';

$.get(file, function(data){
    var lines = data.responseText.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++) {
        $('.ms-listviewtable tr').eq(i).find('td.ms-lastCell').text(lines[i]);
    }
});
```

I have not tested the AJAX but it should point you in the correct direction, you can use AJAX to return the response text from the .txt file, split it on a character (in your case, a line break), then loop through the table rows, replacing the text in the last cell of each row with the corresponding line.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6vWS/), demonstrating the code to loop through the lines.